# No such file or directory with "-" as the name of the file

Tags: python, file, error-handling, directory, runtime-error

I'm trying to loop through the sub-directories, as follows:

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for directory in dirs:
            for files in os.listdir(path + '/' + directory):
            ...
```

The weird thing is that I'm getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/xyz/Desktop/images/sample/-'
```

Where did `-` come from? I only have two images in the subdirectory, and not sure why it is showing me `-`.

Thanks.

Comment: You should check how `os.walk()` works. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm for an example.

Comment: Hmmmm, could the error come from `...` (assuming that it's a placeholder for other lines of code)?

Comment: @CristiFati Actually `...` is a valid Python expression.

Comment: For the '...', I just had it here in the question to show that there is some code going there, but not showing it in my question